# Norm of a bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

could anyone please help me with the following question? Given $l^{1}:\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n,...)=\frac{2a_1}{3}+\frac{4a_2}{9}+\frac{8a_3}{27}+...+\frac{2^{n}a_n}{3^{n}}+...$ decide whether $f$ is a bounded linear functional. If so calculate $||f||$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I'm voting to close this question as   because you show no work of your own. If you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $|f(a)|\leq |\frac{2a_1}{3}|+|\frac{4a_2}{9}|+...\leq |\frac{2a_1}{3}|+|\frac{2a_2}{3}|+...=\frac{2}{3}\|a\|_1$

And the case $a=(1,0,0,...)$.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you for the help I appreciate it.